# How to use the s3 hook in airflow

Tags: python, amazon-s3, airflow

I have an s3 folder location, that I am moving to GCS.
I am using Airflow to make the movements happen.

In this environment, my s3 is an "ever growing" folder, meaning we do not delete files after we get them.

```
def GetFiles(**kwargs):
    foundfiles = False

    s3 = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='S3_BDEX')
    s3.get_conn()
    bucket = s3.get_bucket(
        bucket_name='/file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs'
    )
    files = s3.list_prefixes(bucket_name='/file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs')
    print("BUCKET:  {}".format(files))


check_for_file = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='Check_FTP_and_Download',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=GetFiles,
    dag=dag
)
```

What I need here is the list of files and their creation date/time.  This way I can compare existing files to determine if they are new or not.

I know I can connect, because the function `get_bucket` function worked.
However, in this case, I get the following errors:

```
Invalid bucket name "/file.share.external.bdex.com/Offrs": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"
```

Thank you

Comment: A bucket name cannot contain a leading / in the name, try without it. Also you need to pass only the bucket name, not the full path, means that /Offrs should go away as well.

Comment: where do I put Offrs then?  because if I just do the first half, i get a "not found" error

Comment: Can you try `files = s3_hook.list_prefixes(bucket_name='s3://file.share.external.bdex.com', prefix='Offrs/')` ?

Comment: response: `Invalid bucket name "s3://file.share.external.bdex.com": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$"`

Comment: You don't want the "s3://" in there - that's not part of the bucket name. Try `s3_hook.list_prefixes(bucket_name='file.share.external.bdex.com', prefix='Offrs/')`

Answer (score 2):

1. The bucket name is wrong. If the url is s3://something/path/to/file, then the bucket name is "something".